# Nitrogen deficiency and chloroplast function

Tags: homework, photosynthesis

**Q.** The formation of which of the following in the chloroplast is affected by a deficiency in nitrogen?

(a) Glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
(b) Starch
(c) Enzymes
(d) Carbohydrates

**My thoughts:**

Nitrogen is used in both of chlorophyll and in converting carbohydrates into proteins so I am puzzled between glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate and enzymes.

However, glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate, starch and carbohydrates are nearly identical in this context and enzymes aren’t produced in the chloroplast either.

Comment: This site doesn’t provide a service for people to cheat on their homework.

Comment: This question was asked in a national Biology exam in my country and the majority are split between PGAL (nitrogen is used in chloroplast) and Enzymes (nitrogen is used to convert carbohydrates to proteins) so I wanted to hear other opinions. I’m still new here so I don’t know how this opposes the point of this page?

Comment: Please read the Help on answering Homework questions, of which this is an example. You are required to demonstrate that you have attempted to answer such questions yourself.

Comment: Does my recent edit make it acceptable?

Comment: Yes, except that the English of the question is incorrect. I assume it should be ( even though a little clumsy) “The formation of which of the following is affected…”.

Comment: Fixed, so, what do you think the answer is?

Comment: No idea. I don’t know what PGAL is. Does it contain N? Also, your title is sure to collect down votes. Change it to something like “Nitrogen deficiency and chloroplast function”.

Comment: phosphoglyceraldehyde

Comment: Ok. If only one is correct, the answer should be evident from my previous comment, assuming that they are all made in the chloroplast, which I cannot be certain about as I’m not a plant biochemist.

Comment: Chloroplasts, like mitochondria, contain DNA (in a [circular chromosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroplast_DNA)) and the machinery for reading that DNA to produce RNA and protein. This chromosome encodes many enzymes involved in transcription and translation and also [RUBISCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuBisCO), which is one of the most important enzymes for life on earth!

Comment: so just to be sure, you're saying it's Enzymes?

Comment: I'm not saying anything about the answer. I have no idea what the question writer wants and think this is a badly written question. A nitrogen deficient plant will be be limited in the ability to make proteins and chlorophyll. I would expect that **everything** would be affected eventually ...